# multi_array_view assignment without deep copy?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

How can I reassign a boost multi_array_view to point to a different part of a multi_array? I don't want a deep copy.

```
boost::multi_array<int, 2> a(...);
array_view b = a[indices[index_range(0, 5)][index_range()]];
array_view c = a[indices[index_range(0, 10)][index_range()]];
b = c; // don't work
```

**Boost source:**

```
template <typename ConstMultiArray>
multi_array_ref& operator=(const ConstMultiArray& other) {
    function_requires< 
      multi_array_concepts::
      ConstMultiArrayConcept<ConstMultiArray,NumDims> >();

    // make sure the dimensions agree
    BOOST_ASSERT(other.num_dimensions() == this->num_dimensions());
    BOOST_ASSERT(std::equal(other.shape(),other.shape()+this->num_dimensions(),
                            this->shape()));
    // iterator-based copy
    std::copy(other.begin(),other.end(),this->begin());
    return *this;
}
```

**Update:** I ended up changing the approach in my program to keep a reference to the indices object created by `boost::indices[...]`. Then I can use that object to create a new `array_view` at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `multi_array_ref` models a C++ reference closely:

- it's not re-seatable
- it's semantically an alias for the object it is "bound to"

Somewhat surprisingly, though, the same appears not to be the case for `const_multi_array_ref`. Note these documentation quotes:

> - [Constructors and Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_assignment)
>
> All of the non-const array types in this library provide assignment operatorsoperator=(). Each of the array types multi_array, multi_array_ref, subarray, and array_view can be assigned from any of the others, so long as their shapes match. The const variants, const_multi_array_ref, const_subarray, and const_array_view, can be the source of a copy to an array with matching shape. **Assignment results in a deep (element by element) copy of the data contained within an array**.

This talks about assigning to a mutable array (view).

However:

> - [`const_multi_array_ref(const const_multi_array_ref& x);`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#const_multi_array_ref)
>
> Effects. This constructs a **shallow copy** of x.

### Approaches

Perhaps you can use `const_multi_array_ref` instead.

Otherwise you should probably look to "break" the bind of un-reseatable references in exactly the same way we do it for C++ references: `std::reference_wrapper<>` or similar indirection.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. A multi_array_ref is only good for referencing an entire multi_array, not a view into part of the multi_array, correct?

Comment: Also, if I have a function that returns an `array_view`, do I need to wrap it in a `reference_wrapper` to avoid a deep copy?

Comment: I just realized that it doesn't make much sense to return a `reference_wrapper`. I guess I have to put it on the heap.

Comment: Yup. None of this is special for m-a-r. Is the exact same for c++ references. You can return reference_wrapper just fine. Just don't use it to return a reference to a local. Also m-a-r can be used to refer to any contiguous array,  not just a full boost::multi_array

Comment: I wrote a library that supports subarray “pointer” reseating https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi#pointer-to-subarray